# What's missing here

Tags: init-file, evil

I've got this from a YouTube video about Evil mode but I can't see the entire init file, so I think it's incomplete because it gives me an error.

The idea is to disable Evil mode in some modes. This is the code:

```
(defcustom dotemacs-evil-emacs-state-modes
  '(special-mode
    eshell-mode
    comint-mode
    project-explorer-mode
    git-commit-mode
    diff-mode
    custom-mode
    dired-mode
    calendar-mode
    help-mode)
  `Doc...
  :type '(repeat (symbol))
  :group 'dotemacs)

(dolist (mode dotemacs-evil-emacs-state-modes)
  (evil-set-initial-state mode 'emacs))
```

When I run it, it says `Error: invalid syntax ")"` and it's referring to this block:

```
  '(special-mode
    eshell-mode
    comint-mode
    project-explorer-mode
    git-commit-mode
    diff-mode
    custom-mode
    dired-mode
    calendar-mode
    help-mode)
```

What's wrong with this variable?

*** The final solution:

```
(defcustom dotemacs-evil-emacs-state-modes
  '(special-mode
    eshell-mode
    comint-mode
    project-explorer-mode
    git-commit-mode
    diff-mode
    custom-mode
    dired-mode
    calendar-mode
    help-mode)
  "Documentation..."
  :type '(repeat (symbol))
  :group 'dotemacs)

(dolist (mode dotemacs-evil-emacs-state-modes)
  (evil-set-initial-state mode 'emacs))
```

I changed the DOC to a string variable and made sure that the STANDARD variable is properly spaced with white spaces.

Also, the ")" syntax error was just some package telling me I miss-typed it not an actual run-time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run it, it says `Error: Doc string is missing` which I don't understand.

It means that `defcustom` expects a documentation string but you did not provide one. Use <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `defcustom` <kbd>RET</kbd> to learn where the doc-string is supposed to go and then add it.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to deal with the DOC string but now it says that the second variable `'(special-mode
    eshell-mode
    comint-mode
    project-explorer-mode
    git-commit-mode
    diff-mode
    custom-mode
    dired-mode
    calendar-mode
    help-mode)` has invalid syntax and is missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for a doc-string (or any string for that matter), read the documentation again. It's supposed to look like "Doc...", not `Doc...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. But all that `C-h f` has to say about `Doc` is `DOC is the variable documentation.`

Comment: Well, I suppose you could just look at any elisp file that you know contains a `defcustom` form to see how this is done. Or consult the `elisp` info manual. Also I am not aware of any programming language where strings look like `string but many languages where they look like "string".

Comment: Agree, I didn't know it was supposed to be a string. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: You are welcome, but may I suggest that you do read at least the basic parts of the `elisp` manual. If you don't, then it will always be trail and error, with a focus on the latter ;-)

Comment: By the way, here is the node about `defcustom` (from the `emacs` manual): https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html#Variable-Definitions. It does contain an example.

Comment: I'd like to get to it eventually. I was just testing emacs and trying to set it up with vim keybinds.

Comment: Well, good luck then! I hope you like it. (You might want to try Spacemacs then, it's a starter-kit with a focus on Evil. That might help ease you into the Emacs experience (while sticking mostly to vi/m bindings), without having to learn basic elisp right away.)

Comment: I tried Spacemacs for a while and it felt somewhat heavy. Decided to keep it simple with plain Emacs.

Comment: That's what I would have done too ;-) But some (many) users, like the batteries-included approach.

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it somehow. Changed the DOC to a string and made sure that the '(var var var) is properly spaced out.